# Runtime error:cannot find module "ionic-framework/ionic"

Tags: angular, typescript, debian, ionic2

I am learning angular2/ionic2 and I am trying to learn by creating small apps. This time I wanted to create an app to open an webpage (url). I got error (CANNOT FIND PLATFORM) and solved with help from Stack Overflow.

The app is successfully build but I could not run the app in real device. I am just getting a blank white screen. When I run ionic serve, I am getting runtime error. I have added my .ts file.

Home.ts

```
import {Page} from 'ionic-framework/ionic';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

declare var cordova:any;

@Page({
selector: 'page-home',
templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
constructor(public platform: Platform) {
platform = platform;

}

launch(url) {
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, "_system", "location=true");
});

}

}
```

[image]

app.module.ts

```
  import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
  import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
  import { MyApp } from './app.component';
  import { AboutPage } from '../pages/about/about';
  import { ContactPage } from '../pages/contact/contact';
  import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
  import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';

  @NgModule({
  declarations: [
  MyApp,
  AboutPage,
  ContactPage,
  HomePage,
  TabsPage
  ],
  imports: [
  IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
  MyApp,
  AboutPage,
  ContactPage,
  HomePage,
  TabsPage
  ],
  providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}]
  })
  export class AppModule {}
```

[image]

Comment: can you add your app.module.ts file to the question?

Comment: yes..,one moment

Comment: import {Page} from 'ionic-framework/ionic'; What is this line for? Are you using any component by name 'Page' if so, are you importing it correctly?

Comment: @Page({
selector: 'page-home',
templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

Comment: i think yes.., i imported it correctly..,app is successfully build too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through [Angular Guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/). And check [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/cheatsheet.html).
You should use `Component` not `page`.

```
@Component({
selector: 'page-home',
templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
```

Comment: thank you once again @suraj., this has been solved but still i am getting different runtime error

Comment: i have added a picture of of it. runtime error:cordova is not defined in Homepage

Comment: cordova does not work in ionic serve.. it only loads in device/emulator

Comment: yes you are correct but i just want to launch a url(fr eg.,google)..,i have created a button and if i click the button I am getting the above mentioned error.Now the app is visible in real device but i COULDN't load the webpage